# Why can't i display my products by incrementing the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, innerhtml

I'm trying to display all of my products on the "Our Products" showcase but it's not working. I wonder is there anything wrong with my displayProducts function. The console announces the mistake as "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: productsDOM is not defined".
Thank you for helping me!

This is my js:

```
const cartBtn = document.querySelector('.cart-btn')
const closeCartBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn')
const cartDOM = document.querySelector('.cart')
const cartOverlay = document.querySelector('.cart-overlay')
const cartItems = document.querySelector('.cart-items')
const cartTotal = document.querySelector('.cart-total')
const cartContent = document.querySelector('.cart-content')
const productsDom = document.querySelector('.products-center')
    //cart
let cart = []
    //getting the products
class Products {
    async getProducts() {
        try {
            let result = await fetch('products.json')
            let data = await result.json()
            let products = data.items;
            products = products.map(item => {
                const { title, price } = item.fields;
                const { id } = item.sys;
                const image = item.fields.image.fields.file.url;
                return {
                    title,
                    price,
                    id,
                    image
                }


            })
            return products
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    }
}
//display products
class UI {

    displayProducts(products) {
        let result = '';
        products.forEach(product => {
            result += `
           <!--single product-->
           <article class='product'>
               <div class="img-container">
                   <img src=${product.image} alt="" class="product-img">
                   <button class="bag-btn" data-id=${product.id}>
               <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>add to bag
           </button>
               </div>
               <h3>${product.title}</h3>
               <h4>$${product.price}</h4>
           </article>
           <!--single product-->
                    `
        })
        productsDOM.innerHTML = result;
    }


}
//local storage
class Storage {

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const ui = new UI()
    const products = new Products()
        //get all products
    products.getProducts().then(products => ui.displayProducts(products))

})
```

This is my JSON:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "sys": { "id": "1" },
      "fields": {
        "title": "queen panel bed",
        "price": 10.99,
        "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "./images/product-1.jpeg" } } }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": { "id": "2" },
      "fields": {
        "title": "king panel bed",
        "price": 12.99,
        "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "./images/product-2.jpeg" } } }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": { "id": "3" },
      "fields": {
        "title": "single panel bed",
        "price": 12.99,
        "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "./images/product-3.jpeg" } } }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": { "id": "4" },
      "fields": {
        "title": "twin panel bed",
        "price": 22.99,
        "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "./images/product-4.jpeg" } } }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": { "id": "5" },
      "fields": {
        "title": "fridge",
        "price": 88.99,
        "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "./images/product-5.jpeg" } } }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": { "id": "6" },
      "fields": {
        "title": "dresser",
        "price": 32.99,
        "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "./images/product-6.jpeg" } } }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": { "id": "7" },
      "fields": {
        "title": "couch",
        "price": 45.99,
        "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "./images/product-7.jpeg" } } }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": { "id": "8" },
      "fields": {
        "title": "table",
        "price": 33.99,
        "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "./images/product-8.jpeg" } } }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-center">
            <span class="nav-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
            <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="">
            <div class="cart-btn">
                <span class="nav-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>    
        </span>
                <div class="cart-items">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="hero">
        <div class="banner">
            <h1 class="banner-title">furniture collection</h1>
            <button class="banner-btn">shop now</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="products">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h2>Our Products</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="products-center">



        </div>

    </section>

    <!--cart-->
    <div class="cart-overlay">
        <div class="cart">
            <span class="close-cart">
                <i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>
            </span>
            <h2>your cart</h2>
            <div class="cart-content">
                <!--cart-item-->
                <div class="cart-item">
                    <img src="images/product-1.jpeg" alt="">
                    <div>
                        <h4>queen bed</h4>
                        <h5>$9.00</h5>
                        <span class="remove-item">remove</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
                        <p class="item-amount">1</p>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--end of cart item-->

            </div>
            <div class="cart-footer">
                <h3>your total: $ <span class="cart-total">0</span></h3>
                <button class="clear-cart banner-btn">clear cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--end of cart-->
    </div>
    <script src="cart.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple typo, you define

```
...
const productsDom = document.querySelector('.products-center')
...
```

but use

```
...
productsDOM.innerHTML = result;
...
```

in your function. Case sensitivity matters, so you get an error saying that `productsDOM` doesn't exist - it doesn't, `productsDom` exists instead.

Comment: Btw, can i ask you what does "populate" in this function do? Thank you! "setupAPP() { cart = Storage.getCart() this.setCartValues(cart) this.populate(cart) }". Followed by this function: "static getCart() {
        return localStorage.getItem('cart') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) : []
    }"

Answer (score -2):

The problem in your code was that you made a typo here

```
const productsDom = document.querySelector('.products-center')
// other code 
productsDOM.innerHtml = result;
```

Like you see the decalaration of variable is in camel case but when You use this variable you write it with upper case on the end.

I have wrote this simple example for You. Be free to use it. You can test it here.

```js
let json = '{"items":[{"sys":{"id":"1"},"fields":{"title":"queen panel bed","price":10.99,"image":{"fields":{"file":{"url":"./images/product-1.jpeg"}}}}},{"sys":{"id":"2"},"fields":{"title":"king panel bed","price":12.99,"image":{"fields":{"file":{"url":"./images/product-2.jpeg"}}}}},{"sys":{"id":"3"},"fields":{"title":"single panel bed","price":12.99,"image":{"fields":{"file":{"url":"./images/product-3.jpeg"}}}}},{"sys":{"id":"4"},"fields":{"title":"twin panel bed","price":22.99,"image":{"fields":{"file":{"url":"./images/product-4.jpeg"}}}}},{"sys":{"id":"5"},"fields":{"title":"fridge","price":88.99,"image":{"fields":{"file":{"url":"./images/product-5.jpeg"}}}}},{"sys":{"id":"6"},"fields":{"title":"dresser","price":32.99,"image":{"fields":{"file":{"url":"./images/product-6.jpeg"}}}}},{"sys":{"id":"7"},"fields":{"title":"couch","price":45.99,"image":{"fields":{"file":{"url":"./images/product-7.jpeg"}}}}},{"sys":{"id":"8"},"fields":{"title":"table","price":33.99,"image":{"fields":{"file":{"url":"./images/product-8.jpeg"}}}}}]}';


const productsDom = document.querySelector('.products-center');

//getting the products
class Products {
    getProducts() {
        try {
            let data = JSON.parse(json);
            let products = data.items;
            products = products.map(item => {
                const { title, price } = item.fields;
                const { id } = item.sys;
                const image = item.fields.image.fields.file.url;
                return {
                    title,
                    price,
                    id,
                    image
                };
            })
            return products
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}

//display products
class UI {
    displayProducts(products, element) {
            let html = ''
        products.forEach(product => {
            html += `<article class="product"><div class="img-container"><img src=${product.image} alt="" class="product-img"><button class="bag-btn" data-id=${product.id}><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>add to bag</button></div><h3>${product.title}</h3><h4>$${product.price}</h4></article>`
          });
    
        element.innerHTML = html;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const ui = new UI();
    const products = new Products();
    
    //get all products
    var result = products.getProducts();
    ui.displayProducts(result, productsDom);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-center">
            <span class="nav-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
            <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="">
            <div class="cart-btn">
                <span class="nav-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>    
        </span>
                <div class="cart-items">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="hero">
        <div class="banner">
            <h1 class="banner-title">furniture collection</h1>
            <button class="banner-btn">shop now</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="products">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h2>Our Products</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="products-center">



        </div>

    </section>

    <!--cart-->
    <div class="cart-overlay">
        <div class="cart">
            <span class="close-cart">
                <i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>
            </span>
            <h2>your cart</h2>
            <div class="cart-content">
                <!--cart-item-->
                <div class="cart-item">
                    <img src="images/product-1.jpeg" alt="">
                    <div>
                        <h4>queen bed</h4>
                        <h5>$9.00</h5>
                        <span class="remove-item">remove</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
                        <p class="item-amount">1</p>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--end of cart item-->

            </div>
            <div class="cart-footer">
                <h3>your total: $ <span class="cart-total">0</span></h3>
                <button class="clear-cart banner-btn">clear cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--end of cart-->
    </div>
    <script src="cart.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the issue or solution at all and just copies 90% of the problem with a typo fix and extremely minimal refactoring. Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Ohh sorry, I just wanted to made for him an runable example because there was your answer below with minimal refactoring information, so I don't didn't want to copy You. I edited my answer now it should by ok regarding the rules. I hope You will be the best moderator in the future ;)

Comment: Btw, can i ask you what does "populate" in this function do? Thank you! "setupAPP() { cart = Storage.getCart() this.setCartValues(cart) this.populate(cart) }". Followed by this function: "static getCart() {
        return localStorage.getItem('cart') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) : []
    }"

Comment: @NươngĐàmThị there should be somewhere the populate implementation. You need to find first what kind of object is "this".